# ActiveRecord before_update callback understanding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

Do I understand correctly that if I execute

```
model = Model.create(some_attr: "attr_value")

model.update(some_attr: "new_attr_value")
```

and for Model I have

```
before_update :before_update_callback

def before_update_callback
  some_attr
end
```

that callback will return "new_attr_value", since the internal ruby object (variable "model") changed before the callback was called.

Comment: Returning from a callback does nothing, but yes the value of `some_attr` will be the new value at that point. The value of `some_attr_changed?` will be `true` and the old value will be in `some_attr_was`.

Comment: @rmlockerd prior to Rails 5 returning false from a callback would abort the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Thats exactly what will happen.

```
# Updates the attributes of the model from the passed-in hash and saves the
# record, all wrapped in a transaction. If the object is invalid, the saving
# will fail and false will be returned.
def update(attributes)
  # The following transaction covers any possible database side-effects of the
  # attributes assignment. For example, setting the IDs of a child collection.
  with_transaction_returning_status do
    assign_attributes(attributes)
    save
  end
end
```

See:

- https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html